# How do you select data from multiple tables in the most efficient way?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I Have written 2 Linq to sql querys that work but I don't like the fact that I have to loop through the first query in order to run the second.

There is a foreign key on the second table that references the first tables Id. Can anyone improve the code I have written or is this solution the ideal?

```
using (var entities = new dbEntities())
{
    var groups = (from g in entities.ObjectGroup
                    select g);

    var mappings = (AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ObjectGroupModel>>(groups));

    foreach (var map in mappings) 
    {
        var types = (from t in entities.ObjectTypeToObjectGroupMappings
                        where t.ObjectGroupId == map.Id
                        select t.ObjectTypeId);
        map.ObjectTypeIds = types;
    }

    return mappings;
}
```

Thanks for all you help.

Comment: Your entities should have relations that connect them. If they do, all you have to do is load the root objects and the related ones will be loaded lazily or eagerly. For example, `ObjectTypeToObjectGroupMapping` should have an `ObjectGroup` property, not an ObjectGroupId that needs manual joining. An `ObjectGroup` should have an `ObjectTypes` collection that will load all related types by itself

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var mappings = (from gr in entities.ObjectGroup
                join t in entities.ObjectTypeToObjectGroupMappings
                on gr.Id equals t.ObjectGroupId into subTs
                from subT in subTs.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group new { gr, subT } by new { gr.Id /*and other gr's properties*/} into sub
                select new ObjectGroupModel 
                {
                     Id = sub.Key.Id,
                     /*other gr's properties via propN = sub.Key.propN*/
                     ObjectTypeIds = sub.Where(x => x.subT != null).Select(x => x.subT.ObjectTypeId).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hard-coded joins are the opposite of efficient in an ORM. They are a very strong sign that important relations are missing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, your comment is related to the question, not to my answer.

Comment: It *is* related to the answer. Such code shouldn't be used in production

Comment: This is just answer on existing question, and _Hard-coded join_ is usual approach at production for nоt explicitly related tables and to avoid frequent and separated subqueries at case of lazy loading.